# Why h2 database giving Input/output error accessing h2 database?

Tags: h2

I am getting Input/output error while accessing h2 databse.

We are using Spring JDBCTemplate to access h2 databse.

This issue is happening on production and not able to reproduce on local and qa machines.

Below is the exception we are getting on production.

Really appriciate if some geeks could help me with this.

```
SELECT RECTYPE, PROP_MRKTVAL FROM PA_ULTIMATE.DATA WHERE PBKEY = ? [90031-194]
SELECT RECTYPE, PROP_MRKTVAL FROM PA_ULTIMATE.DATA WHERE PBKEY = ? [90031-194]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: Input/output error"; "/lbs/namedresources/Geoproperty/pa_all/pa_all.h2.db"; SQL statement:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occured while excecuting geoidentity java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT RECTYPE, PROP_MRKTVAL FROM PA_ULTIMATE.DATA WHERE PBKEY = ?]; SQL state [90031]; error code [90031]; IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: Input/output error"; "/lbs/namedresources/Geoproperty/pa_all/pa_all.h2.db"; SQL statement:
"   ... 21 more"
"   at org.h2.store.FileStore.readFully(FileStore.java:272)"
"   at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.readFully(FileUtils.java:356)"
"   at org.h2.store.fs.FileDisk.read(FilePathDisk.java:467)"
"   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:377)"
"   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)"
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
"   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
"   at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)"
"   at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:329)"
"   at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201)"
"   at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:113)"
"   at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36)"
"   at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:309)"
"   at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:341)"
"   at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:655)"
"   at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:542)"
"   at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:468)"
"   at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:169)"
"   at org.h2.index.MultiVersionIndex.find(MultiVersionIndex.java:78)"
"   at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:128)"
"   at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.find(PageBtreeIndex.java:174)"
"   at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.find(PageBtreeIndex.java:184)"
"   at org.h2.index.PageBtreeNode.find(PageBtreeNode.java:309)"
"   at org.h2.index.PageBtreeNode.find(PageBtreeNode.java:308)"
"   at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.getPage(PageBtreeIndex.java:149)"
"   at org.h2.store.PageStore.getPage(PageStore.java:750)"
"   at org.h2.store.PageStore.readPage(PageStore.java:1326)"
"   at org.h2.store.FileStore.readFully(FileStore.java:274)"
"   at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:330)"
"   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)"
"   at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)"
```